# UITableView　numberofrowsinsectionのsectionについて

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

swiftを学習している者です。下記のプログラムで質問があります。

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        let sectionData = tableData[section]
        return sectionData.count
    }
```

各セクションの値が入った配列「tableData」を「sectionData」に取り出して、sectionDataの個数を返していると思いますが、let sectionData = tableData[section]という文でなぜtableDataの後ろに[seciton]をつけているのかがわかりません。

お手数ですが、回答を宜しくお願いします。

**プログラム**

```
import UIKit

let sectionTitle = ["チョウ目","バッタ目","コウチュウ目"]
let tection0 = [("キタテハ","タテハチョウ科"),("クロアゲハ","アゲハチョウ科")]
let section1 = [("キリギリス","キリギリス科"),("ヒナバッタ","バッタ科"),("マツムシ","マツムシ科")]
let section2 = [("ハンミョウ","ハンミョウ科"),("アオオサムシ","オサムシ科"),("チビクワガタ","クワガタムシ科")]
let tableData = [tection0,section1,section2]

class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myTableView:UITableView!
        myTableView = UITableView(frame : view.frame, style : .grouped)

        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self

        view.addSubview(myTableView)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return sectionTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        let sectionData = tableData[section]
        return sectionData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitle[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let sectionData = tableData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section]
        let cellData = sectionData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellData.0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellData.1
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let title = sectionTitle[indexPath.section]
        let sectionData = tableData[indexPath.section]
        let cellData = sectionData[indexPath.row]
        print("\(title)\(cellData.1)")
        print("\(cellData.0)")

    }
}
```

Comment: もし第三者が書いたプログラムであるなら、念のため出典や転載元も明記してもらった方がいいかと思います。

Comment: 何がわからないのかがよくわからないのでコメントにて失礼します。ご自身で書かれているように`tableData`は「各セクションの値が入った配列」です。配列から1つの要素(この場合特定のセクションのデータ)を取り出すには`[ ]`構文を使うことについてはご理解いただいているだろうと思います。なぜその箇所で特定の１つの要素を選ぶことが不要であると感じられるのか、もう少し説明していただくことはできませんか?

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/174898